# Unexpected behavior when using EditText.setSelection()

Tags: android

I am doing a program where users can use regular expressions to search in text, and I want to let the matching text to be selected. So I use this code:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.btn_search:
                    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(reg.getText().toString()).matcher(txt.getText());
                    int start = txt.getSelectionStart();
                    if (start != txt.getSelectionEnd()) {
                        start++;
                    }
                    if (start < 0 || start >= txt.length()) {
                        start = 0;
                    }
                    while (true) {
                        try {
                            m.find(start);
                            txt.setSelection(m.start(), m.end());
                            txt.requestFocus();
                            break;
                        } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                            if (start == 0) {
                                err_notfound.show();
                                break;
                            }
                            start = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        } catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
            err_syntax.show();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            showException("onClick", ex);
        }
    }
```

However the code is not acting as expected. When I put the cursor manually to a position, and then press the search button, sometimes the program will set the cursor to m.start() but do not expand the selection to m.end(). I have tested the program, and m.start() and m.end() are of different values.
If anyone know what causes the problem, please tell me. I'll appreciate it.

Edit: Thank you for helping! I find an answer to the question. It has something to do with the pin which is used to move the cursor and select text (I don't know what it's called...). If it is shown in the textfield, and setSelection() is called, the EditText will not show the selection correctly. However, if you then use getSelectionStart() and getSelectionEnd(), you'll find they are exactly the same value of m.getStart() and m.getEnd(). This could be a bug. So my solution is to call clearFocus() first. The modified code is like this:

```
                    txt.clearFocus();
                    while (true) {
                        try {
                            m.find(start);
                            txt.setSelection(m.start(), m.end());
                            txt.requestFocus();
                            break;
                        } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                            if (start == 0) {
                                err_notfound.show();
                                break;
                            }
                            start = 0;
                        }
                    }
```

And it works.

Comment: From the looks of it, the snippet of code you provided should work just fine. Are you using EditTexts?

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and put in one modiication.

```
 Matcher m = Pattern.compile("1*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(txt.getText());
```

I then made sure that my EditText had only 1's and it highlighted the entire thing.

You many need to confirm that your Regular Expressions are written correctly. You could see more on regualr expressions [here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/72regular/)(same site I just used).

Comment: Sorry. I don't mean that it doesn't work all the time. It doesn't work specifically when I set the cursor to any position in the text and then press the search button. When I immediately press the button after editing the regular expression, it works just fine.

Comment: Do you want to check the entire edit text despite the location of the cursor or only from where the cursor is to the end?